# Regex not matching numbers after hyphen

Tags: regex

I have the following:

```
1.5 5 tablespoon cream
½ (1 cup) heavy cream
¼ – ½ teaspoon cream
1 tablespoon cream

^(?:[\-\.\/\s]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+
```

I'm trying to figure out why `¼ – ½` isn't matching, I have a escaped hyphen inside the non capture group.

**What I've tried:**

`^(?:[\-\.\/\s\W]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+` but it matches the `½ (1`, I just want everything as long as it contains dots, hyphens, and spaces.

Negative lookahead with the `\W` which tags non-word chars, it captures exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but the negative lookahead doesn't block the `1 (1` from being captured, here is what I tried: `^(?:[\-\.\/\s\W]*(?!\()*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+`

https://regex101.com/r/bITQ4F/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hyphen" in your text is actually an [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (hex 2013 or decimal 8211), not a regular hyphen (hex 2D or decimal 45).

Copy-paste (so you grab the en dash) and use this:

```
^(?:[-–./\s]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+
```

which has both the regular hyphen and the en dash character in the character class.

Note that none of the characters in the character class need escaping, even the hyphen because it's first and in that position it doesn't need to be escaped.

If you want to add the [EM DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) too, copy `—` and paste it at the end of the character class.

---

If your tool/language supports POSIX character classes (likely), you can use the *dash punctuation* class `Pd`:

```
^(?:[\p{Pd}./\s]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+
```

which is more readable.

Comment: So I think there is a unicode character class for dashes (Dash Punctuation), if c++ is an option: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/character_classes/optional_char_class_names.html

Comment: Whaaaat.. speechless! It would've taken me a million years to even begin suspecting that Glen, your answer is my tylenol.

Comment: @BurnsBA yes, it's `\p{Pd}`. I've updated the answer with that alternative. Thanks for reminding me it exists.

Comment: The / after the dot needs to be escaped though @Bohemian

Comment: @Johnson depends on your language. Some languages (like JS) *delimit* regex using the slash, and in that case you need to escape the slash, but genreally not - the slash has no special meaning in regex.

Comment: PHP in my case. I understand now, appreciate all the clarification.